# WP8: C++ memory leak detection like CRT library

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-debugging

Microsoft Visual Studio offers the CRT library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx) for memory leak "detection". But this library does not work on Windows Phone 8. Is there a compareable method/library to analyse memory leaks in Windows Phone 8 C/C++ code?

Regards,